# Minkowski's Linear Forms Theorem With Complex Coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, nt.number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

Minkowski's Linear Forms Theorem is often stated about linear forms with real coefficients.  However, in Narkiewicz's *Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers*, the following generalization of Minkowski's Linear Forms Theorem is stated (the theorem is actually stated for a general lattice in real space, but I'm only interested in the case where the lattice is $\mathbb{Z}^N$):

Let  $U = \{ L_j(x_1, \ldots, x_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N  a_{ij} x_i \mid 1 \leq j \leq N \}$ be a system of $N$ linear forms with complex coefficients satisfying the following condition: if $L_j \in U$, then the conjugate form, $\overline{L_j} \in U$.  Let $M = [a_{jk}]_{1\leq j,k \leq N}$.  Let $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_N \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i \geq | \det M |$ and $L_i = \overline{L_j}$ implies $\epsilon_i = \epsilon_j$.  Then there exists a nonzero point $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ such that $|L_j(x_1,\ldots,x_N)| \leq \epsilon_j$ for each $1 \leq j \leq N$ with strict inequality holding for all but one $j$.

However, instead of providing a proof, Narkiewicz refers to two books by Cassels, both of which only prove the case where the coefficients of the forms are real.  The proof of the real version---which uses Minkowski's Convex Body Theorem on $M^{-1} ([-1,1]^N)$---does not easily generalize to the complex version.  Does anyone have an idea of how the proof of the generalization might go?  I've tried translating the problem to real-space (using the fact that $N$-dimensional complex space is isomorphic to $2N$-dimensional real space), but the set that I want to apply Minkowski's Convex Body Theorem to does not have large enough volume.

EDIT: A proof may appear in the 39th "chapter" in Minkowski's *Geometrie der Zahlen* (on page 113).  However, I cannot read German.  Does anyone know of an English translation of the work?

Comment: A proof can be found, e.g., in Hecke's *Lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers* (Theorem 95, pp. 104--105 in the English translation). I can currently access this on Google Books: https://books.google.com/books?id=uR_pBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR7&dq=lectures%20on%20the%20theory%20of%20algebraic%20numbers&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @so-calledfriendDon Thank you very much!  Of course, I'm just now seeing this after I made it through the proof myself with a big hint from Minkowski and the aid of Google Translate.  On the bright side, I understand the proof very thoroughly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit where it's due to @so-calledfriendDon who found a source before I figured this out.  However, I figure I'll post the proof because Google Books can be a finicky thing.

First, note that we can assume that all $\epsilon_j = 1$.  If not, replace $L_j$ by $\frac{L_j}{\epsilon_j}$ and note that all of the hypotheses pertaining to forms and their conjugates still hold.

Suppose there are $r$ forms which have real coefficients and $s$ pairs of complex conjugate forms so that $r + 2s = N$.  Without loss of generality, $L_1, \ldots, L_r$ have real coefficients and $\bar{L}_{r+j} = L_{r+s+j}$ for each $1 \leq j \leq s$.  Then we can write $$L_{r+j} = \frac{R_j + i I_j}{\sqrt{2}} \\ L_{r+s+j} = \frac{R_j - i I_j}{\sqrt{2}}$$ for linear forms with real coefficients $R_j$ and $I_j$ and $1 \leq j \leq s$.  Observe that if we look at the set of forms $L_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq r$ and $R_k, I_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq s$, we have $r + 2s = N$ linear forms in $N$ variables, where all the linear forms have real coefficients.  In particular, using the fact that $\bar{a}_{r+j,k} = a_{r+s+j,k}$ for all $1 \leq j \leq s$ and $1 \leq k \leq N$ (this is simply restating that $\bar{L}_{r+j} = L_{r+s+j}$), we can explicitly describe $R_j$ and $I_j$: $$ R_j(x_1, \ldots, x_N) = \sqrt{2} \text{Re}[a_{r+j,1}]x_1 + \cdots + \sqrt{2} \text{Re}[a_{r+j,N}] x_N \\ I_j(x_1, \ldots, x_N) = \sqrt{2} \text{Im}[a_{r+j,1}]x_1 + \cdots + \sqrt{2} \text{Im}[a_{r+j,N}] x_N$$

Let $A$ be the matrix whose entries are the coefficients of the forms $L_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq r$ and $R_k, I_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq s$.  I won't go into the gory details, but using elementary properties of determinants, you can show that $|\det(A)| = |\det(M)| \leq 1$.  Now you can apply the version of Minkowski's Linear Forms Theorem where the coefficients of the linear forms are real (proofs of this theorem are plentiful) to find a nonzero point $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_N) \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ where $|L_1(\mathbf{x})| \leq 1$, $|L_j(\mathbf{x})| < 1$ for $2 \leq j \leq r$ and $|R_k(\mathbf{x})|, |I_k(\mathbf{x})| < 1$ for each $1 \leq k \leq s$.

But then we have, for each $1 \leq j \leq s$ $$|L_{r+j}(\mathbf{x})|^2 = \left|\frac{R_j(\mathbf{x}) + i I_j(\mathbf{x})}{\sqrt{2}} \right|^2 = \frac{R_j(\mathbf{x})^2 + I_j(\mathbf{x})^2}{2} < 1 \\ |L_{r+s+j}(\mathbf{x})|^2 = \left|\frac{R_j(\mathbf{x}) - i I_j(\mathbf{x})}{\sqrt{2}} \right|^2 = \frac{R_j(\mathbf{x})^2 + I_j(\mathbf{x})^2}{2} < 1$$.

This shows that $|L_1(\mathbf{x})| \leq 1$ and for each $2 \leq j \leq N$, we have $|L_j(\mathbf{x})| < 1$, which is exactly what we wanted.